# Jenkins - Delete deployed artifacts on job delete

Tags: git, maven, jenkins, dsl

Currently, I'm creating a Jenkins job that automatically creates new Jenkins jobs when new branches are created in a Git repository. It should also be deleted when the branches are deleted. This works so easily.

But these new jobs deploy their artifacts to a remote server. And once an automatically created job is deleted, all created artifacts should be deleted. And here I do not know any more.

To deploy the artifacts I use Jenkins Artifact Deployer plugin.
For the automatic creation of the jobs I wrote a job DSL script (this also deletes the jobs).

Here is a photo of the settings of Jenkins Artifact Deployer plugin:
[image]

I hope someone can help me.

greetings

Answer (score 0):

- You can use <kbd>Execute a groovy script when the job is deleted</kbd> option.
- In Groovy script, Call the `Delete API` of the `remote server` where you are storing your artifact with proper `Authentication`.

Comment: This function I have tried already, but this does not delete already deployed builds when the job is deleted.

Answer (score 0):

We have the same setup with automatically created and deleted jobs per branch. We also have a cleanup job, which deletes outdates workspaces on all nodes.

But we never thought about deleting the artifacts from repository on job deletion. We solved this from the repository side. At least in our case there are some cleanup jobs available in Nexus Artifact Repository, which we use to delete outdated artifacts.